# Nodejs DNS verify using HTTP file upload

Tags: node.js

I am trying to verify my DNS to get an SSL certificate using the file upload verification method:

[image]

[image]

I am using Nodejs express and did this:

```
router.get("/.well-known/pki-validation/6BFB7F1676F92A093F1BF1E6E425082F.txt",async function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('./6BFB7F1676F92A093F1BF1E6E425082F.txt',{root: __dirname})
})
```

When i go the the url I can see the contents of the file. But when I click verify I get:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What CA is that? Maybe they require a specific `Content-Type`? For instance let's encrypt explicitly requires `text/plain` as content type for the challenge result ... And I know it's a dumb question: But are you sure, your server is reachable from the outside?

Comment: And you could also check if you have for instance an additional whitespace or line break in your file.

Answer (score 2):

with expressjs try this code in index.js file to verify with "HTTP file upload" method:

```
...
app.get('/.well-known/pki-validation/2CBXXXXX_HTTP_FILE_UPLOAD_VERIFY_METHOD.txt', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('2CBXXXXX_HTTP_FILE_UPLOAD_VERIFY_METHOD content');
});
...
```